# Setting aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to true throws MethodAccessException in REST based JSON WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

In my application's web.config. On, some servers if I set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=true

`<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />`

I get "MethodAccessException". I need to use aspNetCompatibilityEnabled. Since, i want this call to be authenticated by one of ours HttpModule. I googled every where no answer found. It seems like there is an IIS setting that can fix it. Since, It is working in some internal environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to put:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

above your service class declaration?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple WCFServices  than add this in all services

```cs
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```